# Como inserir novo objeto no arquivo json

Tags: c#, json

Segue arquivo json:

```
[{"Id":0,"Nome":"","Endereco":""}]
```

Segue a classe:

```
public class JsonResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Segue código:

```
string jsonToOutput = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader($@"{pathname}\file.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    var array = JArray.Parse(json);
    List<JsonResult> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>>(json);

    var last = items[items.Count - 1].Id + 1;

    var itemToAdd = new JObject
    {
        ["Id"] = last,
        ["Nome"] = textBox_nome.Text,
        ["Endereco"] = textBox_endereco.Text
    };
    array.Add(itemToAdd);
    jsonToOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array, Formatting.None);
}

using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText($@"{pathname}\file.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(file, jsonToOutput);
}
```

Resultado que eu quero:

```
[{"Id":0,"Nome":"","Endereco":""},{"Id":1,"Nome":"","Endereco":""}]
```

Resultado final:

```
"[{\"Id\":0,\"Nome\":\"\",\"Endereco\":\"\"},{\"Id\":1,\"Nome\":\"\",\"Endereco\":\"\"}]"
```

**Segunda tentativa:**

```
string jsonToOutput = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader($@"{pathname}\file.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    List<JsonResult> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>>(json);
    int last = items[items.Count - 1].Id + 1;
    List<JsonResult> _data = new List<JsonResult>
    {
        new JsonResult()
        {
            Id = last,
            Nome = "",
            Endereco = ""
        }
    };
    items.AddRange(_data);

    jsonToOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
}

using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText($@"{pathname}\file.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(file, jsonToOutput);
}
```

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Já tentou imprimir o valor de `jsonToOutput` pra ver se ele está correto? Acho que o erro está ali

Comment: Qual a diferença entre o resultado obtido e o esperado?

Comment: @LINQ No arquivo original está sem "\", com o código acima está salvando "\" no arquivo. Já tentei com `Replace` não resolve.

Comment: Acho que você tá fazendo a serialização do objeto duas vezes. A primeira vez tu atribui ao `jsonToOutput`, a segunda tu manda pro arquivo no `Serialize`.

Comment: O resultado final ta certo porque é um texto. e as barras são de escape ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, na segunda vez, dá pau na linha `List<JsonResult> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>>(json);`

Comment: Código de erro: 'Error converting value "[{"Id":0,"Nome":"","Endereco":""},{"Id":1,"Nome":"","Endereco":""}]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EBF.Json+JsonResult]'. Path '', line 1, position 89.'

Comment: Não é por causa das barras ?

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou `File.WriteAllText($@"{pathname}\file.json", jsonToOutput);` Acho que colega @mutlei tem razão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com os comentários (com o input do autor da resposta), o erro era que o objeto estava sendo serializado duas vezes.

Tanto aqui:

```
jsonToOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
```

Quanto aqui:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(file, jsonToOutput);
```

O problema é que na ultima linha, está serializando um objeto já serializado. Logo a string formada na segunda serialização é a primeira com a formatação correta toda escapada (com um `\"` que impede a interpretação normal das aspas (`"`)).

Então, é momento se escrever o objeto serializado.

```
File.WriteAllText($@"{pathname}\file.json", jsonToOutput);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você está pegando um `json`, jogando numa lista, adicionando um novo item, convertendo novamente para `json` e salvando.

Para isso basta fazer o `SerializeObject` da lista,

```
string json = "[{\"Id\":0,\"Nome\":\"\",\"Endereco\":\"\"},{\"Id\":1,\"Nome\":\"\",\"Endereco\":\"\"}]";
List<JsonResult> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>>(json);

var last = items[items.Count - 1].Id + 1;

items.Add(new JsonResult()
{
    Id = last,
    Nome = "Leonardo",
    Endereco = "Rua de baixo"
});

string myJsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
```

A variável `myJsonOutput`  vai gerar uma string `json` e assim você poderá salvar que não ira "pegar" os escapes

Deixei também no [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vi2Pq6) para referencia